# Android Navigation Drawer Doesn't Pass onTouchEvent to Activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have an `Activity` which uses the Android `NavigationDrawer`.
When using only `fragment`s (as usual), everything works perfect.
But now I want to use this `drawer` on other activities of my app, and for some of them,
I don't want the main view to be a `fragment`.

**Question**
The problem is, the `onTouchEvent()` of the `activity` itself (and the `onItemClickedListener()` of a child `ListView` for that matter) isn't called, because the `drawer` consumes it.
Of course, I want it to be called:)
Needless to say, I would hope the answer will be simple (even a XML one), and hopefully not by extending the `Drawer` class (unless that's what it takes of course).

**More Info**
The Activity's main layout is very simple, basically a `ListView` and the `DrawerLayout` on top of it (below in XML).
The `Drawer` has one `fragment` as it's `childView` (for fragment navigation) and of course, the `ListView` for the `Drawer` Items.

I've seen many questions regarding (not exactly) similar issues, and the frequent answer was to use `onInterceptTouch()`, `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()` on the `DrawerLayout`, and on the Parent view (`Activity`'s main content) and even `onTouchEvent()` (with False returned) on the `ListView` of the Drawer.
Nothing seems to do the trick.

[I read this link](http://devsbuild.it/files/PRE_andevcon_mastering-the-android-touch-system.pdf)
and it does seem like using Intercept methods somewhere could be the answer. But how?

Please let me know if you need any code. But it's a very basic code/layout for this matter.
Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apparently the answer is somewhat easy, although it does make you extend the DrawerLayout and do some thinking, and maybe will result in some strange results (using the LAST
example, I haven't seen any, yet).

Anyway, related questions which looking backwards can help understanding the issue (will explain about the first one later on):
1. [DrawerLayout prevents call of MainActivity.onTouchEvent()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040150/drawerlayout-prevents-call-of-mainactivity-ontouchevent)
2. [How can I requestDisallowTouchEvents on Android DrawerLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329458/how-can-i-requestdisallowtouchevents-on-android-drawerlayout)
3. [Set drag margin for Android Navigation Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988597/set-drag-margin-for-android-navigation-drawer/17802569#17802569)

**Answer**
First, please note that I put lots of examples here. If you just want the best one (for me), jump to the last one.
Secondly, if someone has enough reputation, please comment on the first link's question and put a link to this answer (it can help that guy).

**Example 1**
Well, basically, just extend Android's DrawerLayout and replace onTouchEvent() to this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
    super.onTouchEvent(arg0);
    return false;
}
```

This solution will do anything except that it won't open the Drawer on slides, only menu clicks and the like. Besides, it forwards clicks so when the Drawer is open
for instance, touching outside of it will NOT close it, but click on whatever is behind (e.g. a ListView). Le'ts try harder...

**Example 2**
Now, let's catch the open OR visible cases, to return true (and consume the action at the Drawer).

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
    super.onTouchEvent(arg0);

    if(isDrawerOpen(findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu)) || 
            isDrawerVisible(findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu))){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This solution is better, as it prevents clicks on behind the Drawer when the drawer is open or even visible (slide starts...). But touch-sliding it still doesn't work.

**Example 3**
Ok, so let's just split cases. Touches (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) inside the Drawer's margin (area that Google desided to slide Drawer when touched at) 
will result in returning True to consume the action, and others will forward the event (return False).

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
    super.onTouchEvent(arg0);
    float edge = 30;//that's for a left drawer obviously. Use <parentWidth - 30> for the right one.
    View mDrawerListView = findViewById(R.id.drawer_listview);

    if(isDrawerOpen(mDrawerListView) || 
            isDrawerVisible(mDrawerListView)){
        return true;
    } else if(arg0.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && arg0.getX() > edge){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Note that I used 30dp. That's what I found to be the margin (although in one of the links it is said to be 20....).

Well, the next example would of course be deciding what is, exactly, that edge (see in code above) value is, according to Android. We don't want to 
use a number that could change or whatever.

**New Question**
So now that first link should come handy. It "hacks" the Drawer code to get that Drawer edge/megin number. BUT, it didn't work for me, as those exact Field names could not be found.
I run mDrawerLayout.getClass().getField() which returns all the fields, but without any luck finding what we want.  Anyone?

**Last Example - Full Code**
Ok, looking on example number 3, after understanding what exactly I did, we can make it faster by extending the onFinishInflate() method and save it as a global variable
for this CustomDrawerLayout for later use. We can also put that first 'if' inside the second one to save some more work. OK here goes:

```
View mDrawerListView;
...

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    mDrawerListView = findViewById(R.id.drawer_listview);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    super.onTouchEvent(event);

    if(event.getX() > 30 && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        if(isDrawerOpen(mDrawerListView) || isDrawerVisible(mDrawerListView)){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

That's it for now! Hope it'll helps someone in the future beside myself, hehe....

Comment: Nice one. I wonder if there is a cleaner solution (the Navigation Drawer could release the touch events that it does not use, couldn't it...)

Comment: well, I guess you could come up with one. You have to read how touch events are forwarded in Android (which can get tricky), and then override the Drawer's onTouchEvent() or onInterceptTouchEvent().

Comment: I don't remember why it didn't work for me, but I guess it had too many side effects...Here are two links which can give you an idea:
[link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040150/drawerlayout-prevents-call-of-mainactivity-ontouchevent),  [link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605491/prevent-drawerlayout-from-handling-touches-in-content-area), and a link explaining how touch works [how touch works](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. For my needs, I it to works with a one-liner in `onTouchEvent`: just do `return isDrawerVisible(mDrawerListView)`. (Obviously with `super.onTouchEvent(event)` the only other line of the method.)

Comment: @carthurs yes it's simpler, but has side-effects, I put the rest of the code in purpose:)

Comment: @guy_m It's definitely over-complicated; for example, `isDrawerVisible() || isDrawerOpen()` is redundant; `isDrawerVisible()` is always true when `isDrawerOpen()` is true https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#isDrawerOpen(android.view.View)

Comment: Well, I can easily see it now (this code of mine is very old), but the first condition ('if') is important

Answer (score 1):

While working on the same problem I was inspired by [guy_m's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2774781/guy-m) and boiled down his proposals to the following solution.

Again it amounts to extending DrawerLayout and overriding onInterceptTouchEvent(). The logic is simple:

- Whenever the touch event occurs **off the drawer view** (the slideable part), we return false. Then our DrawerLayout is out of the game when it comes to handling the event -- the event is handled by whatever view we put **into** the DrawerLayout at the respective position.
- On the other hand, when the event occurs **inside the drawer view**, we delegate to super.onInterceptTouchEvent() to decide what to do with the event. That way the drawer will slide in and out as before on touch gestures happening on itself.

The following code sample is for a DrawerLayout whose drawer view is located on the right (android:gravity="right"). It should be obvious how to modify it to cover also the case of a left-placed drawer.

```
public class CustomDrawerLayout extends DrawerLayout
{
  @Override
  public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent( MotionEvent event )
  {
    final View drawerView = getChildAt( 1 );
    final ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get( getContext() );
    // Calculate the area on the right border of the screen on which
    // the DrawerLayout should *always* intercept touch events.
    // In case the drawer is closed, we still want the DrawerLayout
    // to respond to touch/drag gestures there and reopen the drawer!
    final int rightBoundary = getWidth() - 2 * config.getScaledTouchSlop();

    // If the drawer is opened and the event happened
    // on its surface, or if the event happened on the
    // right border of the layout, then we let DrawerLayout
    // decide if it wants to intercept (and properly handle)
    // the event.
    // Otherwise we disallow DrawerLayout to intercept (return false),
    // thereby letting its child views handle the event.
    return ( isDrawerOpen( drawerView ) && drawerView.getLeft() <= event.getX()
            || rightBoundary <= event.getX() )
            && super.onInterceptTouchEvent( event );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With these answers, i still had some trouble. I could get the motionEvent back to the activity but I lost the onClick listener answer by fragment or everything on the screen. So I found another way to have everything work ( get answer when override OntouchEvent from activity, and answer to onClick Listener )

Extend DrawerLayout and Override this methode :

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if(super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)) return true;
    else {
        Activity activity = AppContext.getCurrentActivity();
        return activity.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

if the drawer want the motion event, let it handle it. And if not, pass the event to activity yourself. (AppContext.getCurrentActivity is something from you with current activity, you can for instance attach activity as weakreference to the drawerLayout OnCreate)

The good thing with this way, you don't care about the edge and don't care if start or end. And you don't care also if it is open or close. Everything work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution:

Set `OnTouchListener` on the screen layout (the first childview of `DrawerLayout`, normally) and transmit the `TouchEvent` to a custom `GestureDetector`.

So, you can do your own things in it. One more important thing: if you want to override `onSingleTapUp()` or something else, you should `return true` in `onDown()` to make sure that you can get the rest `MotionEvent` to make `onSingleTapUp()` work.

```
private class MyGestureListener implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        // do your own things
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return false;
    }


}
```

and set it :

```
 mGestureDetector=new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureListener());

    layout_content.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            return  mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To add on to guy_m 's answer, here is my implementation for a drawer that opens from the right, includes constructors so that it is viewable in the layout editor and also takes into account when a user swipes from past the edge point:

```
public class CustomDrawerLayout extends DrawerLayout {
View mDrawerListView;
float edge;
int holddown = 0;
static final String TAG = CustomDrawerLayout.class.getSimpleName();

public CustomDrawerLayout(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
    setscreendimensionvals(context);
}

public CustomDrawerLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setscreendimensionvals(context);
}

public CustomDrawerLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setscreendimensionvals(context);
}

private void setscreendimensionvals(Context context){
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    /*((Activity) context).getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay()
            .getMetrics(displayMetrics); */
    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    float density = displayMetrics.density;
    edge = width - (30 * density); // 30 is the edge of the screen where the navigation drawer comes out
    Log.d(TAG,"edge: " + edge);
    Log.d(TAG,"width: " + width);
}
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    mDrawerListView = findViewById(R.id.drawerconstraint_overworld);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    super.onTouchEvent(event); // need to add action up and a local variable to detect when lifted finger
    //Log.d(TAG,"point: " + event.getX());
    if(event.getX() >= edge && (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)){
        holddown = 1;
        //Log.d(TAG,"hold down");
    }

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        holddown = 0;
        //Log.d(TAG,"hold up");
    }

    if(holddown == 1){
        return  true;
    }else{
        if(isDrawerOpen(mDrawerListView) || isDrawerVisible(mDrawerListView)){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might have the unfortunate luck of encountering as persistent an issue as this one, I will add onto the others' answers with my own problem case and solution in the hopes that fewer souls will face this nightmare of a headscratcher.

Due notice is that my explanation will most likely work for any swipeable view **whose parent is** `DrawerLayout` (e.g. this solution only works for views that are children of `DrawerLayout`), but I will regale my experience and my toils for the purpose of clarity.

---

In my case, I needed to have a `MaterialCalendarView` ([3rd-party `CalendarView` on steroids](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview)) in a `DrawerLayout` with a `NavigationView` to the right (i.e. with `"android:gravity"="end"`). It wasn't long after implementing the view hierarchy that I realised there had existed a conflict between the swipe events of my `NavigationView` and `MaterialCalendarView`.

In essence, what occured was that whenever I began swiping the `MaterialCalendarView` to the **right** in order to **swipe back to the next month**, I wound up **triggering the** `DrawerLayout`'**s touch event interceptor and closing said** `DrawerLayout` **instead of swiping to the previous month**.

So, the solution should be easy, shouldn't it? Set a `onTouchListener`on the `MaterialCalendarView`, call `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()`, and call it a day—akin to this in the view-hosting Activity:

```
calendar.setOnTouchListener { _, motionEvent ->
            when(motionEvent.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                    drawerLayout.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
                }
            }
            true
        }
```

...and you should be all set?

Well, the fact that I'm answering *here* is enough to infer that wasn't the case and that my `onTouchListener` wasn't, like the rest, being triggered.

After extensively scouring this thread and trying to follow everyone's advice, I came at a point wherein none of the solutions offered were helpful for someone who'd simply wanted to "exclude" a view from being detected by the `DrawerLayout`'s touch event interceptor. Some ideas entirely paralysed my touch event infrastructure, while others simply gave me more of the same behaviour. I had hit a roadblock and I didn't know what to do.

Then, an epiphany.

---

I realised that due to my inexperience with writing custom views I'd missed the glaringly obvious: what I needed to do was simply find out where the `MaterialCalendarView` was, get its coordinates, and see if any touch events are inside  in order to call the proper implementation (be it the Activity or default `DrawerLayout` one)! And, of course, since in the former, the `onTouchListener` *disables* interception of touch events by the `DrawerLayout`, that meant only the `MaterialCalendarView` could handle the swipes! It was so simple!

And fast-forward to learning about `MotionEvent`s, reading up on what the heck a `Rect` was, and a muddy in-between of crashes, I finally wrote the custom `DrawerLayout` which responded to my swipes on the `MaterialCalendarView` only with the Activity implementation and ignored the ones outside, opting for the `DrawerLayout` touch interceptor:

```
class EventCalendarDrawerLayout : DrawerLayout {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : this(context, attrs, 0)
    
    lateinit var calendar: MaterialCalendarView
    lateinit var drawer: View

    override fun onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate()
        drawer = getChildAt(1)
        calendar = findViewById(R.id.event_calendar)
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        val rect = Rect()
        calendar.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect) // get the calendar rect positions

        // respond to proper motions and forward events contained inside the calendar's rect only
        if((event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE ||
                    event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && rect.contains(event.x.roundToInt(), event.y.roundToInt())) {
            return (context as Activity).onTouchEvent(event)
        }

        // otherwise return the default intercept touch event response
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)
    }
}
```

It's not rocket science, truly, but it is something I deemed worth showing, as it was new and unexpected for me (and undoubtedly many others yet to venture here). Nevertheless, I believe that this implementation may work to ignore as many views embedded inside `DrawerLayout`s as one could possibly wish for.